# Notepad++ replace regex keeping medium part and replacing beginning and end

Tags: regex, notepad++

i need to replace the following lines:

```
http://www.domainname.com/media/sights/1Brooklyn_Bridge.jpg
......................................
......................................
......................................
http://www.domainname.com/media/sights/100Central_Park.jpg
```

To

```
{{media url="sights/1Brooklyn_Bridge.jpg"}} 
......................................
......................................
......................................
{{media url="sights/100Central_Park.jpg"}}
```

How do i do that using notepad++ regex?

Answer (score 1):

regex : `^(http://www.domainname.com/media)(.*)$`
replacement :`{{media url="$2"}}`

Comment: your regex did not work, what worked was (http://www.domainname.com/media\/)(.+jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this it will work

Find:  `^.*m/(.+a)/(.+)`

Replace:  `{{$1 url="$2`

I tested it on my Mobile notepad